# Applying the central limit theorem when the means are distinct?

Tags: central-limit-theorem, maximum-likelihood, linear-regression

Suppose $\epsilon_1,...,\epsilon_n$ are i.i.d random variables with normal distribution $N(0,\sigma^2)$, and for $i=1,...,n$ we have
$$Y_i=\beta_0+\beta_1x_i+\beta_2z_i+\epsilon_i.$$

I have found the maximum likelihood estimator $\hat \beta_0=\frac{1}{n}\sum_iY_i$. I am asked to then use the central limit theorem to deduce the approximate distribution of $\hat \beta_0$ when $n$ is large in the cases where we no longer assume the $\epsilon_i$ are normally distributed.

I am confused as the CLT requires the $n$ random variables that are i.i.d. but the mean of each $Y_i$ is $\beta_0+\beta_1x_i+\beta_2z_i$ which are not necessarily the same . Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a hand-wavy application of the CLT. The $Y_i - E[Y_i] = \epsilon_i$ are presumably i.i.d. with mean zero, so $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_i (Y_i - E[Y_i])$ converges in distribution to some normal distribution $N(0, \sigma^2)$ as $n \to \infty$.

They probably then want you to say that for large $n$, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_i (Y_i - E[Y_i])$ is approximately $N(0, \sigma^2)$, and then rearrange this to say that $\frac{1}{n} \sum_i Y_i$ is approximately normal with some mean involving the $E[Y_i]$ and $n$.

Comment: Ah OK that makes sense. Would it be possible to use a similar method to find the distribution for say $$\hat\beta_1=\frac{\sum_ix_iy_i}{\sum_ix_i^2}?$$

Comment: @jaycneek Yes, this is a linear combination of the $y_i$, so I think it should again be a linear transformation of some normal distribution.

Comment: I have messed around for a little while trying to figure it out for $\hat \beta_1$ but I just can't see how to incorporate the $x_iy_i$ products. Could I ask for a hint if possible?

Comment: @jaycneek Sorry, I don't think the expression you've given for $\hat{\beta}_1$ is correct for your model $y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i + \beta_2 z_2 + \epsilon_i$. In any case you might consider asking a separate question.

Comment: It is also assumed that $\sum x_i$, $\sum z_i$, and $\sum x_iz_i$ are all zero